# Dio download multipart

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

Is there any way to download big file as multipart form data with flutter dio package ?
I try this but only download first part :

```
var stream = StreamController<Uint8List>();
Sink<Uint8List> sink = stream.sink;

var reqOpts = Options(headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}, responseType: ResponseType.stream);
var uri = Uri.http(serverBaseUrl, download);
Response<ResponseBody> response = await _dio.post(uri.toString(), options: reqOpts, data: request-data, onReceiveProgress: progressCallback);  

response.data!.stream.listen((chunkBytes) async {
        sink.add(chunkBytes);
      }, onDone: () {
        developer.log("Chunk completely downloaded");
      }, onError: (err) {
        sink.close();
        developer.log("Failed to download file");
      });
```

Note: my server accept post method